# Getting an error System.UnautohrizedAccessException when want to unlock the folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I already can lock the specific folder in c# by using below code:

```
public void SetAccess()
        {
            DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:/Test");

            var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);

            DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

            myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Deny));

            myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);

            this.Hide();

            this.Close();
        }
```

However, when I want to unlock the folder, I am getting an error below:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to perform an unauthorized
>   operation.

by using this code below:

```
public void RemoveAccess()
{
    DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:/Test");

    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);

    DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

    myDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));

    myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);

    MessageBox.Show("Folder Unlocked!");

    this.Hide();

    this.Close();
}
```

The error pointed in this line of code:

```
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
```

Anyone could help me?

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you set permission to that folder?

Comment: It looks like you are locking yourself out in the first part. So the second part fails because you revoked read access which would be required for the second part to run.

Comment: You removed FileSystemRights.Read, that *also* removes the right to read permissions.  You probably like FileSystemRights.ReadData better.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner: Then, to unlock the locked folder it cannot be done by code, because of the folder's permission sir? It has to go through the folder's properties?

Comment: @HansPassant: I already done that sir, but it still cannot.. It still remains locked, even though I already run to unlock the folder